# Swing: The Order of Execution of Functions

Tags: java, mysql, swing, concurrency

In one of my DBMS projects that is implemented using **Java Swing** and **MySQL**, I have come across a very interesting problem.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
if(source == insert){
    insertRecord(columnNames, numOfColumns);
    getAllRecords();
    displayAllRecords();
}
```

**WHAT IS EXPECTED:**

This code is a part of an event handler that decides what to do when a button is clicked.

When the user wants to insert a record he clicks the button and the `insertRecord()` function is called. This insert function is inherited from an abstract class.

After inserting the `getAllRecords()` function executes a "SELECT" query and stores the result into a global ResultSet.

Then the `displayAllRecords()` function displays the records on the screen in a table.

**WHAT APPARENTLY HAPPENS:**

While the `insertRecord()` function is being executed, the other two functions `getAllRecords()` and `displayAllRecords()` are also executed.

This means that instead of showing my data after insertion it shows the data that is present before insertion.

**THE QUESTION:**

This appears to be a problem related to Concurrency in Swing and threads, but is there any simple solution that I can apply to make the code work the way I want it to that will not affect my program adversely?

*(If you want to take a look at other pieces of code, please tell me in the comments and I will post them as edits. The original code is very long and hence I did not post it.)*

---

EDIT 1: Added code for the methods mentioned above:

**CODE FOR getAllRecords()**

```
public void getAllRecords(){
    // res is a global ResultSet field  
    try{
        res = sqlConn.getStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error obtaining data!");
    }
}
```

**CODE FOR : displayAllRecords()**

```
public void displayAllRecords() {

    try{
        table = new JTable(buildTableModel());      // code provided at bottom
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected error!");
    }
    displayResult();
}
```

**CODE FOR displayResult()**

```
public void displayResult(){
    //updates the view port of the JScrollPane that is used for the table
    tablePane.getViewport().remove(table);
    table.revalidate();
    tablePane.getViewport().add(table);
    custFrame.repaint();
}
```

**CODE FOR buildTableModel()**

```
public DefaultTableModel buildTableModel() throws SQLException{
    //res is a global ResultSet field
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    ResultSetMetaData metadata = res.getMetaData();

    //getting names of columns
    int columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
        columnNames.add(metadata.getColumnName(i+1));
    }

    //getting all data
    while(res.next()){
        Vector<Object> vec = new Vector<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++){
            vec.add(res.getObject(i+1));
        }
        data.add(vec);
    }
    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);        
}
```

**CODE FOR insertRecord()**

```
public void insertRecord(ArrayList<String> columnNames, int numOfColumns){

    //creation of the GUI... don't know if it matters so kept it
    formFrame = new JFrame("INSERT DATA IN TABLE");
    labelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    textList  = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    submit = new JButton("SUBMIT");      
    prompt = new JLabel("Enter all the details:");

    formFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    formFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    formFrame.setResizable(false);
    formFrame.setAutoRequestFocus(true);

    formFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    formFrame.add(prompt, gbc);
    gbc.gridy++;

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfColumns; i++, gbc.gridy++){

        labelList.add(new JLabel());
        labelList.get(i).setText(columnNames.get(i).toUpperCase());
        formFrame.add(labelList.get(i), gbc);

    }

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfColumns; i++, gbc.gridy++){

        textList.add(new JTextField(30));
        formFrame.add(textList.get(i), gbc);

    }

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2;
    formFrame.add(submit, gbc);

    formFrame.pack();
    formFrame.setVisible(true); 

    // creation and processing of the insert query

    class InsertHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            String query = "INSERT INTO " + tableName
                    + " VALUES( "; 

            int numOfColumns = textList.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < numOfColumns - 1; ++i){
                query +=  "'" + textList.get(i).getText() + "', ";
            }

            query += "'" + textList.get(numOfColumns-1).getText() + "')";

            try {
                sqlConn.getStatement().executeUpdate(query);
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insertion failed!");
            }

        }

    };

    submit.addActionListener(new InsertHandler());

}
```

*(Sorry, the code is so long and complicated. I have tried to comment it wherever I can. I will appreciate any kind of help that you can provide.)*

Comment: The problem is in your code. Show us the code of these methods. A single threa, the Event Dispatch Thread, is used here.

Comment: I've met similar problems on concurrency in Swing. In a program I first move a JPanel by a custom method, then get the location after moving; however every time I get the location before the moving.

Comment: Added the code. Also commented it to make it more understandable, since I am a student and my method of programming might be a bit crude looking.

Comment: +1 For a well written question. The problem is mainly an issue with Concurrency. not sure but perhaps a read of the docs might help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: @JBNizet: Please can you help me with solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insertRecord()` method doesn't insert records in the database. All it does is displaying a new frame. Yet you expect that right after you've displayed this new frame, the records are inserted and ready to be read and displayed. That's not the case.

To be inserted, the user must stare at the frame, finish his cup of coffee, go to the bathroom, come back, and finally decide to click on the submit button. Then, and only then, the data will be inserted in the database. But the `getAllRecords()` and `displayAllRecords()` methods will have been executed for a long time, because as soon as the frame is displayed, the execution of the calling method continues.

So, you have two solutions here:

1. replace the frame displayed by `insertRecord()` by a modal JDialog. A modal JDialog will block the execution until the dialog has been closed. You'll then be able to check if the user has indeed clicked the submit button, and refresh the displayed data.
2. call the methods refreshing the data in the `InsertHandler.actionPerformed()` method, after the data has been inserted successfully.

Comment: So what this means is that my `insertRecord()` function does not wait for the user's input, but rather just displays the form and returns. And when the user does his input that is not a part of the `insertRecord()` method. Right?

Comment: You got it. A modal JDialog will have the behaviour you expect. Otherwise, Swing is event based, and never blocks waiting for user input.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I really appreciate your looking through my code and helping me.

Comment: I have a request. Can you please show me how I can use the modal dialog approach in my program? Just an example or a slice of code will help.

Comment: The code would be almost identical to what you have now. Instead of `new JFrame()`, you would use `new JDialog(true)`. Just make sure setVisible(true) is called last, because everything after setVisible(true) will be blocked until the user closes the dialog.

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot. Solved the problem. The most important part was the `setVisible(true);`. That was what was stopping me.